# Run postgres query in jenkins after build

Tags: postgresql, jenkins

I installed jenkins and postgres on same centos7 server.

I also installed and configured "database" and "PostgreSQL Database Plugin" as shown in this image:

[image]

I want to insert data in my database jenkinsdb (the table i want to work on is "builds") after build is succesfull so i can track history of builds , deployments etc.

How can i run query to my database from jenkins ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script file, let's say build_complete.sh, with the postgresql commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Updated command that solves the bug. Courtesy: YoussefBoudaya's comment.
"export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d jenkinsdb -c "SELECT * FROM builds" postgres"
```

Please confirm psql path from server, it will be similar to `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/psql`.
Add execute script step at the end of your pipeline and simple run your script.

A similar solution can be read [here](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/automating-postgresql-daily-tasks-using-jenkins).

Comment: when i run this command in Jenkins build shell "export PGPASSWORD='postgres';  /usr/bin/postgres -h 172.16.4.26:5432:postgres -d jenkinsdb  -c "Select * from builds" . i get "FATAL:  -c Select * from builds requiert une valeur "

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya I have updated my answer to accommodate the command you are using. You'll need to add port and user as separate variables.

Comment: i solved the first issue now i get  "FATAL: -c Select * from builds requiert une valeur "

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya, it must be due to missing semicolon. Please let me know if ending the command with ";" solves the problem?

Comment: this is the working command : "export PGPASSWORD='postgres'; sudo -u postgres -H -- psql -d jenkinsdb -c "SELECT *  FROM builds" postgres"

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya good that it worked out, I planned to test commands on sandbox environment today.